# Python equivalent of Matlab function to Convert OADate to datetime

Tags: python, matlab

In Matlab, I have a list of doubles that are converted from a System.DateTime in C# to an OADate. In Matlab I can easily convert it to a list like this:

```
symbol1TsData = datetime(symbol1TsDataDouble,'ConvertFrom', 'datenum');
```

What is the equivalent in Python? I tried this but the dates that come back are wrong:

```
symbol1TsData = list(map(datetime.fromtimestamp, symbol1TsDataDouble))
```

Comment: Can you post sample dates? Are these OADates, or some other double representation typical in another language but not Python?

Editing the question to include sample doubles and then the expected date out would be useful to help you.

Comment: Alexander that is exactly corrrect. They are OADates.

Comment: I figured it out. The answer is given here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496683-converting-ole-datetime-values-into-python-datetim/

Comment: Actually I had the same issue and the same recipe helped me as well. I'd recommending posting it as an answer, since Google tends to favor SO so hopefully others will see this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it. OLE time is the number of days (not seconds like epoch!) from 1899, Dec 30 at midnight (weird right?!).

[This](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/496683-converting-ole-datetime-values-into-python-datetim/) might be helpful too.

```
#ole time conversion
import datetime

OLE_TIME_ZERO = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0)

def ole_to_epoch(ole):
    """ Input:  ole - float. Gives ole time, the number of DAYS since midnight 12/30/1899
        Output: float - epoch time
    """
    x = OLE_TIME_ZERO + datetime.timedelta(days=float(ole))
    return (x - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like the following:

```
import datetime

OLE_TIME_ZERO = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0)

def ole_to_epoch(ole):
    """ Input:  ole - float. Gives ole time, the number of DAYS since midnight 12/30/1899
        Output: float - epoch time
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=net-5.0
    """
    days = int(ole)
    hours = abs(ole - days) * 24
    x = OLE_TIME_ZERO + datetime.timedelta(days=int(ole), hours=hours)
    return x
```

E.g.

```
In[0]: ole_to_epoch(-1.25)
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 29, 6, 0)

In[2]: ole_to_epoch(1)
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```